# How to draw any text using drawString() in Java

Tags: java, drawstring

I'm getting into graphical stuff in Java and want to display text. As I've read, `drawString()` is the standard method for this. My code to draw the string is:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextDisplay extends JPanel{
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("My Text", 10, 20);
    }
}
```

The class executing this is:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TextDisplay d = new TextDisplay();
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.getContentPane().add(d);
        f.setSize(200,200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This produces a window with the text "My Text" in it as expected. The question now is: How can I draw any String? With this I have to write the String into the `paint()` method, but I want to input it from somewhere else as a variable.

Comment: just have it as an instance variable?

Comment: You mean like `paint(Graphics g, String s)`? If so, where would this String come from? My main program never actually calls this method.

Comment: no, I mean an instance variable. you cant change the signature of paint(Graphics) and still expect it to work

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `paint()` or draw directly into a `JFrame`.  Draw into a `JPanel` and override `paintComponent()`.  To draw a specific String, store it in an instance field and then call `repaint()`.  You may also want to examine `LineMetrics` and `FontMetrics` to be able to properly center the string.

```java
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawString(mystring, x, y);
}
```

Check out [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) for more on painting.